# Drag Drop ListView rows on Android

Tags: android, listview

How is it possible to create a ListView on Android in which the rows can be dragged and dropped to change its positions. I have seen such example using JQuery:

http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/ajax-todo-list-jquery-php-mysql-css/demo.php

I wonder if someone has ever tried such listView.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to check out my implementation:

- https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview